# Scheduling a product stock reduction BUT wp_schedule_single_event doesn't seem to fire my function

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Inside a private custom plugin for use in the WordPress/woocommerce backend, I need to schedule a product stock reduction.  Using a plugin called [WP Crontrol](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-crontrol/), I am able to see that my wp_cron is successfully recording the scheduling commands, but when I select "Run Now" to test the stock reduction function, it doesn't fire (even though WP Control reports that the task was successful).  I suspected that it had something to do with how I was passing the arguments array in `wp_schedule_single_event`, but I've tried every iteration I can think of.  Can you guys see any red flags in the code below?  Thanks in advance.

Here's part of the function that executes the scheduling function (please note that the event seems to be successfully scheduling at the proper time.):

```
$x=0;
foreach ($robot_array as $index_key => $index_value){
    if ($x <= 1){
        wc_add_order_item_meta($passed_order_item, $index_value['product']['name'], $index_value['product']['sku']); 
        $product = New WC_Product($index_value['product']['id']);
        $product->set_stock(1, 'subtract'); 
        unset($product);
    }  elseif ($x > 1 && $x <= 11){
        wc_add_order_item_meta($passed_order_item, $index_value['product']['name'], $index_value['product']['sku']);
        $time = new DateTime();
        $time->add(add_months($x, $time));
        $args = array($index_value['product']['id']);
        wp_schedule_single_event($time->getTimestamp(), 'cmcs_scheduled_stock_reduction', $args);
        unset($time);
    }
    $x++;
}
```

Here's the function that is supposed to fire:

```
add_action('cmcs_scheduled_stock_reduction', 'cmcs_scheduled_stock_reduction_callback', 10, 2);

function cmcs_scheduled_stock_reduction_callback($args) {
    global $woocommerce, $wpdb;
    $product_id = $args;
    do_action( 'add_debug_info', $args);
    $product = New WC_Product($product_id);
    $product->set_stock(1, 'subtract'); 
    unset($product);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it was, in fact, the way I passed the arguments.  This is implied in resources I've found online, but never explicitly stated: you CANNOT pass a single argument in `wp_schedule_single_event`.  $args must be an array and maps onto variables you arbitrarily define in your hook function.

What I did was add filler values to pass, then reference the element in the array that I want as follows:

```
$x=0;
foreach ($robot_array as $index_key => $index_value){
    if ($x <= 1){
        wc_add_order_item_meta($passed_order_item, $index_value['product']['name'], $index_value['product']['sku']); 
        $product = New WC_Product($index_value['product']['id']);
        $product->set_stock(1, 'subtract'); 
        unset($product);
    }  elseif ($x > 1 && $x <= 11){
        wc_add_order_item_meta($passed_order_item, $index_value['product']['name'], $index_value['product']['sku']);
        $time = new DateTime();
        $time->add(add_months($x, $time));

        //HERE IS THE CHANGE
        wp_schedule_single_event($time->getTimestamp(), 'cmcs_scheduled_stock_reduction', array($index_value['product']['id'],1,2));
        //

        unset($time);
    }
    $x++;
}

add_action('cmcs_scheduled_stock_reduction', 'cmcs_scheduled_stock_reduction_callback', 10, 3);

function cmcs_scheduled_stock_reduction_callback($arg1,$arg2,$arg3) {
    global $woocommerce, $wpdb;
    $product_id = $arg1;
    $product = New WC_Product($product_id);
    $product->set_stock(1, 'subtract'); 
    unset($product);
}
```